# Why are my Spark completed applications still using my worker's disk space?

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

My Datastax Spark completed applications are using my worker's disc space. Therefore my spark can't run because it doesn't have any disk space left.
This is my spark worker directory. These blue lined applications in total take up 92GB but they shouldn't even exist anymore since they are completed applications Thanks for the help don't know where the problem lies.

[image]

This is my spark front UI:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark doesn't automatically clean up the jars transfered to the worker nodes. If you want it to do so, and you're running *Spark Standalone* (YARN is a bit different and won't work the same) you can set `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled` to true, and set the cleanup interval via `spark.worker.cleanup.interval`. This will allow Spark to clean up the data retained in your workers. You may also configure a default TTL for all application directories.

From the docs of `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled`:

> Enable periodic cleanup of worker / application directories. Note that
>   this only affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently. Only the
>   directories of stopped applications are cleaned up.

For more, see [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html).